# Combining list functions

Tags: scala

Below function calculates possible combinations of List elements.

Elements of list which are same are not returned and also just unique elements are returned :

```
def combinations[T](l: List[T]): List[(T,T)] = l match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case h::Nil => Nil
    case h::t => t.map(x=>(h,x)) ++ combinations(t)
}
```

List(1,2,3) returns List((1,2),(1,3),(2,3))

This solution (not mine) is elegant but I would like to know the intuition behind it. Is there a generic property of list elements contained within the code that I'm not aware of? I'm aware why this solution works but I'm unsure of how to arrive at this solution?

Comment: What is the question? To explain why this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually very intuitive when you think about how you would manually build all the combinations. For example, take `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`. To methodically create all the combinations, I will take the first element in the list `1`, and then combine it with all the remaining elements.

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)
```

Those are all the possible combinations that contain `1`. Now let's find all the combinations that contain `2`, but we don't need to include those that have `1`, because we already have them. That means we will take the combinations with the remaining elements of the list.

```
(2, 3), (3, 4)
```

And then with `3`:

```
(3, 4)
```

Do you see the pattern? We take the first element of the list, then pair it with all the remaining elements of the list (the tail). That's this part of the code:

```
case h :: t => t.map(x => (h, x))
 //  1 :: List(2, 3, 4) => List((1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4))
```

Then we move to the next element of the list, and do the same thing. That's the recursive step:  `++ combinations(t)`, and aggregate the results with `++`.

If we started with `1`, then under the covers the first recursive call is `combinations(List(2, 3, 4))`, and we repeat the logic:

```
case h :: t => t.map(x => (h, x))
 //  2 :: List(3, 4) => List((2, 3), (3, 4))
```

And finally:

```
case h :: t => t.map(x => (h, x))
 //  3 :: List(4) => List((3, 4))
```

So we and up with `List((1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)) ++ List((2, 3), (3, 4)) ++ List((3, 4))`

And of course the other cases where there are zero or one elements, cannot produce any more combinations:

```
case Nil => Nil
case h :: Nil => Nil
```

As @0__ stated, the `h :: Nil` can really be handled by `h :: t`, because we'll have this:

```
case h :: t => t.map(x => (h, x)) ++ combinations(t)
//        ^ Nil    ^ Nil maps to Nil          ^ Will hit the first case on the next call, which is also Nil
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining a functional/recursive solution with a `List`, the most simple approach is to cover the basic cases that occur. You then define the partial solutions and add them together.

You want pairs of elements in the output, so you would first figure out that for an empty list (`Nil`) or a list that only contains a single element (`h :: Nil`) there is no partial solution, therefore these two cases have a result of `Nil`. The last case is where you have a head element `h` and a non-empty tail. So produce all the pairs of `h` with each tail element using the `map` function, and repeat recursively for the tail.

Note that technically the middle case is irrelevant. The following suffices:

```
def combinations[A](xs: List[A]): List[(A, A)] = xs match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case h :: t => t.map(h -> _) ++ combinations(t)
}
```